# How to pass an object in a radio button tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For my form I am using my `Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :purchase_date, :send_to_data
end
```

On my form I have the `:purchase_date` working correctly when I create multiple products but also want to make the radio_button_tag do the same:

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_products_path, :method => :post do %>

  <%= date_select("product", "purchase_date")  %>

   <%= radio_button_tag(:send_to_data, 1) %>
   <%= radio_button_tag(:send_to_data, 0) %>


  <% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
     <%= fields_for "products[#{index}]", product do |up| %>
        <%= render "fields", :f => up %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag "Done" %>
<% end %>
```

This didn't work for me, my database doesn't flag as either false or true.

I think the problem lies in the params of the `"send_to_data"`. Unlike the `"purchase_date"` it isn't finding the object (product).

```
{"product"=>{"purchase_date(2i)"=>"12", "purchase_date(3i)"=>"11", "purchase_date(1i)"=>"2011"},
"send_to_data"=>"1", 
"products"=>{"0"=>{"product_name"=>"Test", "price"=>"23", "product_store"=>"13", "exact_url"=>""},
"1"=>{"product_name"=>"", "price"=>"", "product_store"=>"", "exact_url"=>""},
"2"=>{"product_name"=>"", "price"=>"", "product_store"=>"", "exact_url"=>""},
"3"=>{"product_name"=>"", "price"=>"", "product_store"=>"", "exact_url"=>""},
"4"=>{"product_name"=>"", "price"=>"", "product_store"=>"", "exact_url"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Done"}
```

Is there a way to map it to the object like the purchase date does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see you confuse [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and [FormTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html).
You use Form tag helper which, according to the documentation

> (FormTagHelper) provides a number of methods for creating form tags that doesn’t rely
>   on an Active Record object assigned to the template like FormHelper does.

This mean for ActiveRecord-based form you need to use use FormHelper (and its `radio_button` helper method).

Code with [radio_button_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) form tag helper

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:send_to_data, 1) %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:send_to_data, 0) %>
```

generates the following HTML:

```
<input id="send_to_data_1" name="send_to_data" type="radio" value="1" />
<input id="send_to_data_0" name="send_to_data" type="radio" value="0" />
```

And code with [radio_button](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) form helper

```
<%= radio_button("product", :send_to_data, 1) %>
<%= radio_button("product", :send_to_data, 0) %>
```

generates:

```
 <input id="product_send_to_data_1" name="product[send_to_data]" type="radio" value="1" />
 <input id="product_send_to_data_0" name="product[send_to_data]" type="radio" value="0" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

check this page [form_helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) first, here, the right way should be

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:send_to_data, 1) %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:send_to_data, 0) %>
```

Comment: This is strange. I did try this and still get the same results. I have it accessible in my model and I know my Product table has/detects it because my seed data shows the column along with the Products which are flagged as true/false but when creating them it doesn't seem to do it.